# Storing list of objects in a SQL Server database with code-first

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-migrations

*Example*

Let's say the number of answers of multiple choice questions varies. One question can have only 2 choices while another can have 10 choices.

How can I save these multiple choice questions in my SQL Server database? Is the following model viable?

```
public class MultipleChoiceQuestion
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Question { get; set; }

    // Suppose I can have 2-10 answers
    [Required]
    public List<string> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

*Question*

- Can we store a list of objects with various length in a SQL Server database with code-first migration enabled in ASP.NET?
- If it is not applicable, what is the best solution to deal with such problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create another object of type PossibleAnswer that would represent each individual answer for any particular multiple choice question.  Then you would modify your Answers property in your MultipleChoiceQuestion object to be of type List.  PossibleAnswer could be defined as follows:

```
 public class PossibleAnswer {
      public Guid Id {get;set;}
      public Guid MultipleChoiceQuestionId {get;set;}
      public string Answer {get;set;}
 }
```

Comment: I agree, from a normalization standpoint this represents a one to many relationship, which calls for a separate table and required foreign key.

Comment: Got it. But from a technical point of view, is the `MultipleChoiceQuestion` model in my question compilable?

Comment: Oh, do you mean I can have `List<PossibleAnswer>`? Does it imply the database can store lists of objects?

Comment: No, basically with the model specified you would have one table, MultipleChoiceQuestion(s) and another table, PossibleAnswer(s) that would contain the 1 to many relationship between Questions and Answers

Comment: What happens if I execute `select * from MultipleChoiceQuestion`? What will be returned in the field `List<PossibleAnswer>`?

Comment: I think I have misunderstood your reply. I am now using a `[ForeignKey("MultipleChoiceQuestion")]` for reference in `PossibleAnswer`. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you using an ORM like EntityFramework to load your Entities with their data, or are you using standard ADO.NET for accessing your data?  If you are using EntityFramework you would have the option of either Lazy Loading your Navigation Properties or Eager Loading them.  If you are using standard ADO.NET to get at your data you would need to manage loading the possible answers property yourself.

Comment: I am using Web API 2 with Entity Framework in Visual Studio. Thanks for the info. I will check out navigation properties.