# Retrieving data in an ICollection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

*Background*

Since I am new to using Entity Framework, I try to build something simple first. I started a post asking how I can store lists of objects in SQL Server:

- [Storing list of objects in SQL Server database with code-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296902/storing-list-of-objects-in-mssql-database-with-code-first)

Now I have built up two models:

```
public class MultipleChoiceQuestion
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MultipleChoiceQuestionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Question { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ICollection<PossibleChoice> PossibleChoices { get; set; }
}

public class PossibleChoice
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("MultipleChoiceQuestion")]
    public Guid MultipleChoiceQuestionId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ChoiceIndex { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }

    public MultipleChoiceQuestion MultipleChoiceQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

In `QuestionContext : DbContext` I have defined:

```
public DbSet<MultipleChoiceQuestion> McQuestions { get; set; }
```

Besides, I have a controller with a `Get()` endpoint:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/McQuestion")]
public class McQuestionController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<MultipleChoiceQuestion> Get()
    {
        var context = new QuestionContext();
        return context.McQuestions;
    }
}
```

*Question*

When I issue a `GET` request, the following object is returned.

```
[
    {
        "MultipleChoiceQuestionId": "fcaf709e-2f7d-e411-80bb-002219ac77b7",
        "Question": "Which integer is a prime number?",
        "PossibleChoices": null
    },
    {
        "MultipleChoiceQuestionId": "20159ee7-2f7d-e411-80bb-002219ac77b7",
        "Question": "Who is the person invented light bulbs?",
        "PossibleChoices": null
    }
]
```

How can I include the collection `PossibleChoices` in the `GET` result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use context.McQuestions.Include("PossibleChoices").ToList();

However, you need to learn doing things the right way, so it is better to consider this:

1- Use Fluent API to map your entity to your table, you can use some tools to auto generate your entities (POCO) classes if you have already a database, check "[EF 6 Tools Designer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=40762)" Or "[EF Reverse POCO generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838/view/Reviews/2)".

2- Return DTOs from your Web API instead of returning the entities directly, and to map between the entity and the DTO you can use [AutoMapper](http://AutoMapper.org).

Comment: I tried your solution, but an error is returned: `"exceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException"`

Comment: That's because you have a circular reference, so in WebAPIConfig.cs file add this line:             // To stop recursive reference.
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

Comment: I don't quite understand why there is a circular reference. Could you please explain briefly?

Comment: MultipleChoiceQuestion has a collection of PossibleChoices, and each PossibleChoices has a link back to the MultipleChoiceQuestion and so on..., that why using DTO will stop this, because you will remove the MultipleChoiceQuestion from the child dto.